# Append/Concatenate multipe excel data sets using for loop (Python)

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, append, concatenation

I'm trying to merge data from simulations run more efficiently. Currently the data is produced in multiple excel documents in different folders depending on the run set.

To choose the files I pass this code:

```
def XLFiles():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    select_files = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, initialdir='dir', title='Choose Rig Data Files')
    return select_files

select_files = XLFiles()
file_list = list(select_files)
```

This returns a list of all the dir's of the documents in question.

I aim to next merge the data together. This is where I have problems.

I've used:

```
df2 = []

for f in list(select_files):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(f, header=1, skiprows=range(2,50), usecols="H,I")
    df2.append(df1)
```

My issue is this doesn't return a data frame, instead 3 lists. I'm assuming because I did 'df2=[]' however I don't know how to create df2 as a dataframe without any data. Please can you nudge me in the correct direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f, header=1, skiprows=range(2,50), usecols="H,I")
                for f in select_files], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: MaxU thank you this also worked. I'm unaware of the etiquette here as you were first do I give you the tick?

Comment: @OParker, no, you should simply accept that answer that fits your needs best... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of list of `DataFrame`s, if join empty `DataFrame` there is no error:

```
df2 = []
for f in list(select_files):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(f, header=1, skiprows=range(2,50), usecols="H,I")
    df2.append(df1)
df = pd.concat(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works. I can accept it as correct in 8 mins. Greatly appreciated